# How do I rerender only once for multiple state updates?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to modify redux state by dispatching multiple times.
It's something like this:

`changeObjectKey('key', 'newVal')`

I'm calling this multiple times in one function and I only want to render once.
How can I do this?

Comment: if your values are not interlinked with each other and you want to render once ,better call it once ,store the previous values in temp variables and call it once after your calculations.as react render() will call in each new changes in state or props

Comment: If such kind of updates is regular thing while user interacts with your app, specify dedicated action for that purpose and get those state variables updated all at once within your app reducer.

Comment: Other than what @YevgenGorbunkov mentioned, you should probably be OK to ignore the multiple renders. Try not to optimize unless it's really an issue.